# Using an existing table instead of AspNetUsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

**Description**

I am writing a website for the customers so they can book new jobs in our currently existing internal system. There is a SQL database in place I'd like the application to use.

**Problem**

The issue is that I'd like to utilize currently existing usernames and passwords.

**Question**

- How can I tell ASP to instead of using `AspNetUsers` table, use my currently existing `Customers` table?

And

- Instead of using a "password hash" field from it use just password field?

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Answer (score 0):

Use ASP.NET Identity instead of the older ASP.net membership system. It lets you more easily store userdata in an existing table.http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity